# Preventing a duplicate database call in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in one of my Rails views:

```
<% if response.response_variables.where(var_name: variable[0]).present? %>
   <%= response.response_variables.where(var_name: variable[0]).first.var_value %>
<% else %>
   Something else
<% end %>
```

Right now I'm doubling up on the database call doing the if/else. Is there a way to use the database call from the `if` statement so that I don't call the DB twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<% if variable = response.response_variables.where(var_name: variable[0]).first %>
   <%= variable.var_value %>
<% else %>
   Something else
<% end %>
```

Note:

You probably should move this logic into your controller though.

Comment: Showing following warning in console:  warning: found = in conditional, should be ==

Comment: Yeah, those warning are pain in the ass - this is standard ruby way of doing things. You can try wrapping it in brackets `if (var = rvalue)`, I usually just ignore those (Note to myself - seek source of those warnings and destroy it)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's best to keep logic minimal in your views so try to refactor your code so expose as little logic in your views as possible.

Anyway, here's how you could avoid unnecessary db calls:

```
<% response_variable = response.response_variables.find_by(var_name: variable[0]).includes(:var_value) %>
<% if response_variable %>
   <%= response_variable.var_value %>
<% else %>
   Something else
<% end %>
```

In the above code, we assume that `var_value` is an attribute of response_variable. If it isn't an attribute, you can remove the call to `includes`.

Hope that helps!